# Sum of total value of rating from firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, sum

What kind of approaches needed to add the total amount of rating value in firebase? Here i have included the json structure of my firebase. The one needed to be focused on are ratingstar_review.

[image]

Supposedly, the sum of ratingstar_review from first list and second would be 3+5=8. So I would expected to get that total sum 8. Below is the code for retrieving data from firebase to be stored on ratingbar for display.

```
    starRef.child("number_rating").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                float rating = Float.parseFloat(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                star.setRating(rating);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
    });
```

An example would be a helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
starRef.child("Ratings").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int total = 0, 
            count = 0;
        for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            int rating = dataSnapshot.child("ratingstar_review").getValue(Integer.class);
            total = total + rating;
            count = count + 1;
        }
        star.setRating(total);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { 
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

The main differences with your code:

- Since there are multiple child nodes under `/Ratings` the code needs to loop over these children.
- To get the value from each child, you find the correct property with `getChild("ratingstar_review")` and then get it as an integer with `getValue(Integer.class)`.

Comment: thank you for your time and guidance, i have tested your code. It shows there is an error on getChild saying that it cannot resolve method getChild(java.lang.String). Is it because of the ratingbar? because it uses float i assume

Comment: Good catch. The method is called [`child`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot). I fixed the code in my answer.